# Error: FS.Store.S3 you must specify the "bucket" option (meteor.js and s3)

Tags: javascript, meteor, heroku, amazon-s3, image-uploading

I'm following the tutorial here: http://experimentsinmeteor.com/photo-blog-part-1/

I can get my application to run fine when I use:

```
meteor --settings settings.json
```

But when I just use "`meteor`" to start up my local server, or when I deploy the app to my production (on heroku), the app crashes, and I get this output:

```
=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
W20160227-10:30:11.721(-8)? (STDERR)          
W20160227-10:30:11.722(-8)? (STDERR) /Users/*************/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20160227-10:30:11.722(-8)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20160227-10:30:11.722(-8)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20160227-10:30:11.722(-8)? (STDERR) Error: FS.Store.S3 you must specify the "bucket" option
W20160227-10:30:11.723(-8)? (STDERR)     at new FS.Store.S3 (packages/cfs_s3/packages/cfs_s3.js:95:1)
W20160227-10:30:11.723(-8)? (STDERR)     at lib/collections/images.js:2:20
W20160227-10:30:11.723(-8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/**************/www/myapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/lib/collections/images.js:58:4
W20160227-10:30:11.723(-8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/**************/www/myapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:242:10
W20160227-10:30:11.723(-8)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20160227-10:30:11.723(-8)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/***************/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20160227-10:30:11.723(-8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/*************/www/myapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:137:5
=> Exited with code: 8
```

I have this portion of the app structured similar to the way it is done in the tutorial:

I have a .gitignore that only includes settings.json

I have the settings.json file in the root:

```
{
  "AWSAccessKeyId" : "access key",
  "AWSSecretAccessKey" : "secret",
  "AWSBucket" : "bucket name"
}
```

Then I have a lib/collections/images.js file:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  var imageStore = new FS.Store.S3("images", {
    /* OPTIONAL IN MOST CASES */
    region: "us-west-1", // substitute the region you selected


    /* REQUIRED */
    accessKeyId: Meteor.settings.AWSAccessKeyId, 
    secretAccessKey: Meteor.settings.AWSSecretAccessKey, 
    bucket: Meteor.settings.AWSBucket
  });

  Images = new FS.Collection("Images", {
    stores: [imageStore],
    filter: {
      allow: {
        contentTypes: ['image/*']
      }
    }
  });
}

// On the client just create a generic FS Store as don't have
// access (or want access) to S3 settings on client
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  var imageStore = new FS.Store.S3("images");
  Images = new FS.Collection("Images", {
    stores: [imageStore],
    filter: {
      allow: {
        contentTypes: ['image/*']
      },
      onInvalid: function(message) {
        Bert.alert(message);
      }
    }
  });
}

// Allow rules
Images.allow({
  insert: function() { return true; },
  update: function() { return true; }
});
```

I know this works because I am able to store images when I run:

```
meteor --settings settings.json
```

It is only using solely 'meteor' and in production that this error is popping up (checked the heroku logs and showing the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

It is throwing the error because you must specify the location of settings either through the command line or an environment variable.  There's a [good blog post](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/making-use-of-settings-json/) about settings on The Meteor Chef.  There's also a link to how to set heroku environment variables [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).  Basically you use `heroku config:set` and specify your variable.  I believe in this case it'd be something like:

`heroku config:set METEOR_SETTINGS \"$(cat settings.json)\" -p 'Project Name'`